# Compare odt files in svn

Tags: svn

I use svn to store the revisions of my specification files, written with oowrite (OpenOffice.org).
I cannot find the way to compare different revisions of my odt files. It complains that they are binary.

Is there any tool or plugin to compare odt files stores in svn repository?

Comment: In my team some use Windows/TortoiseSVN and some use GNU Linux/kdesvn , eclipse, console or web environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [oodiff](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~moy/opendocument/) like this : `oodiff -u myfile.odt` and if it's a file which is in a SVN workspace it will compare the current version with the one on the server and display the difference in a textual way in the console (requires the installation of `odt2txt`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows you can use **TortoiseSVN**, which installs VBScript files for comparing and merging ODF documents as well as Microsoft Office documents.

You will find these scripts in the folder

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts
```

and you can also modify these scripts to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just learning about ODF, so be gentle if I get this wrong... Your ODT file is really a (zipped) container of many different files.  Perhaps you already know this, but this is the reason you cannot `svn diff` or even `svn diff --force` your ODT file.

I have Googled around and everyone seems to understand this limitation of SVN, even though I have found no explicit mention of it.  Maybe the two links at the bottom of this thread will be of interest:
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-151569.html

Thank you,
Zachary